# The injective envelopes of UHF algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

The following is perhaps trivial common folklore for the knowledgeable people in the field: Let $H=\ell^2$. Let $V\subseteq B(H)$ be the Cartan factor of type IV, the self-adjoint operator space that satisties $ab^*+b^*a\in\mathbb{C}1$ for all $a,b\in V$. It is known that $V$ is isomorphically a Hilbert space, 1-complemented in $B(H)$ but not an injective operator space [[Robertson1991](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100070237),$\S 2$]. If $\pi_1,\pi_2:V\to B(H)$ are two representations of $V$, then $C^*(\pi_1(V))$ and $C^*(\pi_2(V))$ are *-isomorphic $C^*$-algebras. This is the CAR algebra (let's call it $A$), and it must be the $C^*$-envelope of $V$ by the previous sentence. The bicommutant $A''=R$ is the hyperfinite $II_1$ factor, an injective von Neumann algebra.

I just can't be certain of if $R$ is the operator space injective envelope of $V$. The injective envelope of $V$ is order isomorphic to an $AW^*$-algebra, contains (a *-isomorphic copy of) the CAR algebra, and is contained in $R$.

> **Q:** Is $R$ the injective envelope of $V$?

---

**edit:** The injective envelopes of $V$ and $A$ are the same. I just came across the paper by [Argerami & Farenick](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506309). Theorem 4.1 in this paper implies that the injective envelope of the UHF algebras (being separable & simple) are *wild* type III $AW^*$-factors. As the name indicates, perhaps there is no easy description of it.

Just not to leave this question space void, I'm copying below one of the questions posed in this paper.

> **Question:** Are the injective envelopes of the UHF algebras $M_{2^{\infty}}$ and $M_{3^{\infty}}$ equal?